# Trigger on resource from resource

Tags: c#, wpf

Is it possible to change a resource from another resource. I like to change the background of StartButtonRed if the mouse is over StartButtonMain.

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="RedBackgroundActive" ImageSource="/Images/start_red_active.png" Stretch="Fill"/>

<Style x:Key="StartButtonMain" TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleButton}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="MainBackground" ImageSource="/Images/start_main_normal.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="MainBackgroundActive" ImageSource="/Images/start_main_active.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Style.Setters>
    <Style.Triggers>
        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
            <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource MainBackgroundActive}"/>
            // Change the background of StartButtonRed to RedBackgroundActive
        </Trigger>
    </Style.Triggers>
</Style>

<Style x:Key="StartButtonRed" TargetType="{x:Type local:SimpleButton}">
    <Style.Resources>
        <ImageBrush x:Key="RedBackground" ImageSource="/Images/start_red_normal.png" Stretch="Fill"/>
    </Style.Resources>
    <Style.Setters>
        <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
        <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource RedBackground}"/>
        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
    </Style.Setters>
</Style>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but check it out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms745683.aspx, specifically check out the section called "Extending Styles" and the `BasedOn` attribute.

Comment: @Coding Gorilla no but its good to know the BasedOn attribute.

Answer (score 0):

You **can't** do this. Because styles are resources and triggers can only target FrameworkElements from within their own Template or using a Binding to an other actual FrameworkElement, you can't bind to another resource.

You could solve this with [UserControl Triggers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.triggers.aspx).